# Gap between buttons in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the buttons to all stick together without any gap between them to design a calculator.

But there is a gap that i can't get rid of even after trying to remove the borders, padding and margin. How can do that ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

button {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <!-- <div class="output"></div> -->
  <div class="calcKeys">
    <button>+</button>
    <button>-</button>
    <button>X</button>
    <button>÷</button>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <button>=</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>0</button>
    <button>.</button>
    <button>AC</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: easily you can use `gap:0` into the parent so the elements wont have a gap between

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman doesn't work

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman I don't think this works, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the `flex` display style, and set the gap to `0` and `flex-wrap` to `wrap`
and set the buttons `width` to `33.33%`

check this snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

button {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.calcKeys {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <!-- <div class="output"></div> -->
  <div class="calcKeys">
    <button>+</button>
    <button>-</button>
    <button>X</button>
    <button>÷</button>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <button>=</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>0</button>
    <button>.</button>
    <button>AC</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yes!, that works and I have understood your point. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sounds good, gl with the rest ^^

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense, probably even a bit cleaner than the approach that I suggested. Though it still can be helpful if for some reason one can't use flexbox. Cheers!